# Как получить конкретное значение при парсинге xml?

Tags: xml, swift3, парсер

Здравствуйте.

Мне необходимо спарсить значения с сайта:
http://ufa.farfor.ru/getyml/?key=ukAXxeJYZN

Я реализовал это вот так:

```
func parsing() {
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://ufa.farfor.ru/getyml/?key=ukAXxeJYZN")
    let dataUrl = NSData(contentsOf: url as! URL)
    let xmlParser = XMLParser(data: dataUrl as! Data)
    xmlParser.delegate = self
    xmlParser.parse()
}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {
    print("Element's name is \(attributeDict)")
}
```

В итоге успешно вытягиваю значения из первого раздела(сategories) - 
id и его значение.
Мне необходимо вытащить названия(пицца и т.д.).
Как это сделать?

Comment: Это ещё актуально?

Comment: @hedgehogues, да. Так и не нашёл ничего путного.

Comment: Нужно вытаскивать названия и тега `<сategories>`?

Comment: @hedgehogues да, категории

Comment: Почему Вы не используете стандартные библиотеки для парсинга xml?

Comment: @hedgehogues я было хотел использовать libxml. запретили. сказали: нативно делай.

Comment: Структура документа всегда одна и та же?

Comment: @hedgehogues да.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению, swift я не знаю. Поэтому могу предложить псевдокод, который легко переложится на swift. Понятно, что в целом структура документа сохраняется. Значит можем использовать "опорные" символы, для поиска нужных нам объектов.

```
str = getXml(url)
indexStartCategories = str.find("<categories>") // Получаем индекс первого символа тега
indexFinishCategories = str.find("</categories>") // Получаем индекс первого символа закрывающего тега

while True:
    indexCategory = str[indexStartCategories:].find("<category") + len("<category") // Получаем индекс начала тега <category>
    indexStartName = str[indexStartCategories:].find(">") + 1 // Индекс начала названия
    indexFinishName = str[indexStartCategories:].find("<") - 1 // Индекс конца названия
    if indexStartName < indexFinishCategories:
        name = str[indexStartName : indexFinishName] // Выделяем текст внутри тега
    else:
        break
```

Прокомментирую. Ищем **особые** подстроки. Эти особые подстроки являются тегами. Заметим, что все нужные нам данные лежат внутри `<categories></categories>`. Далее найдём все нужные нам данные. Очевидно, они лежат между тегами: `<category id="*"></category>`, -- их нам нужно выделить.

Comment: дошло! Понял..Спасибо вам огромное!